# Can you disable Windows Explorer from starting with Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I would like to disable Windows Explorer from starting up. Mainly because I want to attempt working only out of the Task Manager using the Run dialog.

I am aware you're not supposed to, but I am curious if it's possible or not.

Comment: If you are using Windows Server, you can use a Core installation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're running Windows XP/Vista/7:

1. Open the start menu.
2. Type "regedit" (without the `"`) and hit enter ([UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) might come up).
3. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE → Software → Microsoft → Windows NT → CurrentVersion → Winlogon.
4. Change the value of "Shell" to the .exe you want to use.

Reference: http://windows7themes.net/how-to-replace-explorer-exe-in-windows-7.html

For Windows 9x:

1. Open C:\windows\system.ini with the editor.
2. Replace the Shell=explorer.exe line with Shell=your.exe.

Reference: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/trench/3458.html

You can set taskmgr.exe to be your shell.

Comment: thanks for the info. I wasn't sure what to include since the question was not specific about the system used.

Comment: Just summarize the most important steps in your own words, that would be great!

Comment: all changes done :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, yes. Though as you state, not ideal. Without the main explorer.exe running, you will not have a desktop/window manager unless you start or are [running another one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows).

However, for Windows XP the steps to disable explorer on startup should be:

Go to Start -> Run -> Type in `regedit` and press enter.

Navigate to the following tree structure:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> CurrentVersion -> Winlogon

Change the value of the `Shell` key to blank, or another program to start instead of explorer.exe