# On start up only launch one program and shut down on exit

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, boot, shutdown

OS - Windows 7 Professional.

I have a requirement to install software on a computer which will launch automatically on startup and shutdown the computer on exit.  Both of which I can do using Windows StartUp and system shutdown commands.

However I also have the following requirements

1. Users have NO access to desktop
2. Users have NO access to file system (explorer.exe)
3. Users cannot launch or run any other progams.

I have seen that I could [disable explorer.exe on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/435275/can-you-disable-windows-explorer-from-starting-with-windows) but I have no plan to replace it with anything.... What consequences would that have?

In summary yes this computer will only run 1 user program....  (Its for a medical device and its users will not need to use it for anything else - and authorities wont allow access to any other program etc....).

Obviously I also need to think about maintenence of the software (i.e. updating files or the whole exe) - so I would need to have a "backdoor/maintenance password" which would allow access to files...

*If need be I could tell the customer that they need to use a different OS if this is not possible in the current chose one*

Comment: You would replace explorer.exe as shell with your application. That's the first step.

Comment: You want to purchase sotware that will place the system in Kiosk mode there are several both paid and free solutions that do this. I just suggest them on this website for obvious reasons.  Just takes a little bit of [research](http://www.mirabyte.com/en/products/frontface-lockdown-tool/) to find solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the program as "shell", that should take care of launching it at startup and not launching explorer.exe. Create a limited user and only give it the permissions it needs (for example, do not allow to start task manager or explorer.exe). Set the system to autologin to that user.

Your program should initiate the shutdown upon exit itself (or write a script that waits for the program to close and shuts down the computer).

For updates etc you will have another user with full permissions and a good password.

However, physical security is also important - make sure that there is no way to boot the computer from a CD, floppy, network or USB device or to remove the hard drive (all of those options can allow the user to reset the admin password or just access the files).