# Opening Alternative exe to explorer for Specific User

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, boot, login

I'm looking to prevent `explorer.exe` from loading for a specific user and load an alternative application.

I've seen many examples of how this can be completed here for example: [Can you disable Windows Explorer from starting with Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/435275/can-you-disable-windows-explorer-from-starting-with-windows)

I'm concious though that the change is being made to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` which I would assume would be a global effect rather than on an individual user account.

Will changing the registry settings in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` apply to all users?

If it does, is there a different method to opening an application within program files for a specific user account?

Thanks

Comment: "Will changing the registry settings in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE apply to all users?" Yes, as with everything in "HKEY_Local_Machine" it's a machine-level setting.  I'm surprised you didn't figure that out on your own when you did your research and tried it before coming here. :/

Comment: Well I did to be honest hence the question of completing it at a `current user` level.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? What the OP asked was both legitimate and possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to accomplish this.

**In the registry:**
First, make sure that user is currently logged onto the machine, since you'll be modifying HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  Fire up Regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

If the key does not exist, create it.  Then, create a REG_SZ value called Shell.  You can set the value to whatever you want.  When this key is present, it will load whatever you specify rather than explorer.exe when the user logs on.

If the user doesn't have local admin rights, you can do this from your account and mount their NTUSER.DAT registry hive under HKEY_USERS.  Just remember to unmount it again when you're done.

---

**If the computer is domain-joined, then you can use Group Policy**

You must create a new GPO for this, as you want it applying to only the one user.  The setting to modify is:

```
User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System
```

Select Custom User Interface and configure whatever program you want to replace the user's shell.

Since this is a per-user setting, you must link this GPO into the **USER's** OU, not the computer's OU.  Then you will want to use the delegation tab to deny access to the GPO to everyone but this one person.  Alternatively, you can place the user into their own OU and link it there instead.